# Using Leaflet.PolylineMeasure on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I'm trying to use this plugin called [Leaflet.PolylineMeasure](https://github.com/ppete2/Leaflet.PolylineMeasure) and integrate it into my application. The only issue is that the plugin is in JavaScript while my application is in Angular..

I saw that you can npm install the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.polylinemeasure but I'm not sure how to use it after that. I tried doing `L.control.polylineMeasure`, but it says `Property 'polylineMeasure' does not exist on type 'typeof control'`. Most likely because `L` doesn't have the polylineMeasure function in there.

I am using [ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) to run leaflet on my application. How can I get it to work on my angular app?

Comment: Did you include the `Leaflet.PolylineMeasure` script in your app? Make sure your scripts are imported in the order shown in the demo and `polylineMeasure` should be available on `control`: https://github.com/ppete2/Leaflet.PolylineMeasure/blob/master/demo1.html

Answer (score 0):

Luckily you have type definitions available for this Leaflet plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet.polylinemeasure

Therefore you just install them in your TypeScript  / Angular project: `npm install --save-dev @types/leaflet.polylinemeasure`

Make sure you `import` the plugin alongside Leaflet, and the TypeScript compiler should now be happy.